# Listing out pages under categories

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

I have three tables and am trying to get the Category names with the pages listed underneath. Here are what my tables look like

```
TABLE page
id_page | id_category
  1          1            
  2          1  
  3          1
  4          2
  5          2
  6          2          

TABLE page_category
id_category | name
    1         Category 1
    2         Category 2

TABLE page_lang
id_page | title  | content 
   1      Page 1   content
   2      Page 2   content
   3      Page 3   content
   4      Page 4   content
   5      Page 5   content
   6      Page 6   content
```

How would I get this to be displayed on the page like so? The template I am having to work with is a tpl using smarties.

```
Category 1
Page1
Page2
Page3

Category 2
Page 4
Page 5
Page 6
```

Comment: Can you show what attempts you have made thus far?

Comment: I have tried creating an array using the category title as the key with each page underneath it, but couldn't get that to work properly. I have tried the group_concat like below, but when trying to output it to smarty it isn't cooperating either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `group_concat` to comma seperate the tiles of each category.

```
select c.name, group_concat(l.title)
from page_category c
inner join page p on p.id_category = c.id_category
inner join page_lang l on l.id_page = cp.id_page
group by c.name
```